# [Como verificar se a minha lista possui letras ou palavras em Pyton]

Tags: python

Possuo uma lista em Python e preciso saber se possui alguma palavra ou letra, pois preciso que ela só tenha números

```
    def sum_of_products(lista):
if type(lista) != int:
    print("Possui letras")
else:
    print("Somente Numeros")
```

Pensei em algo mais ou menos assim, mas não encontro a solução.

Comment: E se possuir a *string* `'42'`, que é uma *string* numérica, o que deve acontecer?

Comment: Ele teria que recusar e entender como se fosse uma palavra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supondo que você tem uma lista:

```
lista = [1,232,723,221,'numero',3455]
```

De forma simples, você precisa checar pelos ITEMS da lista, não pela lista:

```
for item in lista:
    if type(item) != int:
        pass
```

Agora verificando se existe de forma mais compacta:

```
possui_letras = any(type(item) != int for item in lista)
if possui_letras:
    print("Possui letras")
else:
    print("Somente Numeros")
```

Comment: Extamente isso que eu precisava, funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!